# Respond to a Symfony security annotation with something more than an error page

Tags: php, symfony

I want to implement a data log for attempts against my application. One of this will be when someone without the security rights wants to go to a certain page. For example a normal user trying to go to a url only avaiable for an administrator.

Symfony offers this security annotation:

```
/**
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
```

And for now I use it to display an error page. But what I would like to do is to send the data to a database in case someone attempts to go in the admin only site recurrently (three or more times in less than a minute). The kind of data I will store is user, in case someone is logged in, IP, timestamp, among others. I already have a service that does the storing I just want to know if there is a way to know that someone is trying to access the page repeatedly without authorization and how to call my service in that case.

I have been looking all over the symfony documentation and couldn't find any information relevant to my problem. I would appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**

I did what [@ShiraNai7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385572/shiranai7) told me to plus this in the service declaration in order to be able to use my other service. Thanks.

```
app.exception_listener:
            class: InnoGames\Bundle\OfficeITBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
            arguments: [@service_container]
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a listner for the [kernel.exception](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception) event and do your logging there.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // do your logging here
}
```

Also see Symfony docs - [How to Create Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html)

Comment: Seems like something that might work. The only thing is how to implement my service if i don't have the get() method to do  `$service = $this->get('myService') `

Comment: There's an example in the documentation I linked to. While you're tagging your listener with *kernel.event_listener*, you might as well inject dependencies into it. You don't need the entire DI container. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container